# Pandas quirk using sets as data type

Tags: python, pandas, set

I'm trying to augment an existing data frame with a set data type column. I'm iterating over the rows of the data frame and adding to each set, however the update is being applied to every row, i.e.,

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame()
>>> df['foo'] = [set()] * 2                                                                                                                          
>>> df
  foo
0  {}
1  {}

>>> df.ix[0, 'foo'].update([1, 2, 3])    
>>> df
         foo
0  {1, 2, 3}
1  {1, 2, 3}
```

Does anyone know why this may be happening and/or an alternative mechanism for using sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you are using the same copy of set instance at both index:

```
df['foo'] = [set()] * 2
```

So, when you try to update, the values are added in both the sets.

Instead, create a different instance:

```
df['foo'] = [set() for _ in range(2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['foo'] = [set()] * 2   
df.loc[0, 'foo'] = set([1, 2, 3])
print (df)
         foo
0  {1, 2, 3}
1         {}
```

Also it works with `ix`, but deprecated in next version of [pandas](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-ix):

```
df.ix[0, 'foo'] = set([1, 2, 3])
print (df)
         foo
0  {1, 2, 3}
1         {}
```

***Warning***: non-scalar entries aren't really supported by pandas and so you're going to be at risk of unexpected bugs. Sometimes it's useful despite this, but I've actually been bitten by some in the past.